# Connect to MySQL database remotely in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I tried using this code to connect, but it doesn't work:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
//line 4        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://example.com:3306/db", "user", "pass");

    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String sql = ("SELECT * FROM users;");
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    if(rs.next()) { 
     int id = rs.getInt("id"); 
     String str1 = rs.getString("imei");
     System.out.print(id+"+++"+str1);
```

I receive this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user'@'ip' (using
>   password: YES) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)

This user has all privileges to the database. How do I fix this?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/230012/mysql-access-denied-for-user-rootx-x-x-x

Comment: How can I access mysql command line in cpanel? to do them?

Comment: http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enable-remote-mysql-connections-in-cpanel/ i hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Write following command into remote machine Mysql Server.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password'; 

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This command helps you to connect remote machine to your machine

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have Grant for `'ip'`

Try this:-

```
grant all privileges on db.* to 'user'@'%' to allow connections originating from anywhere
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though that the user already has all the privileges, you still need to deliver the user information in a line like this:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db-name","user","password");
```

You have to replace "db-name" for the name of your database, "user" for the user you created and "password" for the password of the user (if you don't have a password then leave it as "").

You can even create a variable type Connection and added to your code in case you need this in the future, like:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db-name","user","password");
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

To access database remotely from java you need to set database user access permission to access data from anywhere execute following query in your mysql terminal/

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'mysql_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

In above query `%` shows that `mysql_user` can access `database_name` database from any ip globally. If you want to allow  specific ip then replace your ip with `%`